# Transfer ownership of Github repo to someone who has forked it

Tags: git, github

I have forked a repo on Github and made my own modified version of the code. After helping out the original repo's dev with some code, he's ready to retire from it himself and wants to transfer ownership of it to me. Problem is that apparently Github doesn't like to transfer ownerships when someone has has a fork of that repo on their account. The fork I have is mostly new code that will slowly be worked into the original repo, so I want to keep it up to date with original repo and don't want to break it off as its own separate repo.

From playing around with some empty test repos and forks, is this the proper way to transfer the original repo to me without losing or merging my personal changes within my fork:

1. on repo1, add fork's url as a remote.
2. create new branch on repo1 using the hash of the fork, effectively cloning the fork into repo1.
3. Push cloned branch to repo1 on Github.
4. Delete the fork from my account on Github.
5. current owner transfer's ownership (and therefor also the branch containing my modified code) to me on Github.
6. Continue business as usual now owning the original repo which contains a branch that used to be my fork.

I apologize for any incorrect terminology, I'm still fairly new to using git and Github, so still trying to figure out all of its possibilities.

Answer (score -1):

I know this is an old post but...

Could you not make a pull request, have the owner of the original repo merge your changes into his. Then you can remove your forjust transfer the rep to you

Comment: As this is currently phrased, it isn't an answer, this is a comment; and comments as answers [aren't allowed](https://superuser.com/help/deleted-answers) even if they're correct. Please have a look at [how to write a good answer](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer) and see what you can do to improve this one. Left as is it will get deleted. "Could you not" is a bit comment-y, there are a few typos... please remember that SE is not a forum. These are Q&A sites, so the concept is a bit different. I've got no doubts you can fix this one and share some valuable knowledge in the future :-)